# How to send message in Node.js webapp using rabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

So I have a working full stack Node.js webapp deployed at www.infinity2o.com

When I'm developing it locally I have the frontend hitting the backend API by proxy from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:5000` by adding to my `package.json`:

```
"proxy": {
    "/auth/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
},
```

My problem is that when my backend API sends a message (`msg`) to my RabbitMQ server on EC2 with the following code:

```
        await amqp.connect(
            'amqp://infinity2o:2134711@52.4.101.52:5672',
            function(err, conn) {
                conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
                    let q = 'run_minerva_for_new_user_queue';
                    let msg = mongoDBUserId;
                    ch.assertQueue(q, { durable: false });
                    ch.sendToQueue(q, new Buffer(msg));
                    console.log(' [x] Sent %s', msg);
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
                    conn.close();
                    process.exit(0);
                }, 500);
            }
        );
```

My frontend webapp's backend server says:

```
Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/current_user from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED)
```

The thing is I don't understand why hitting a different part of my backend API would cause this problem because `/api/current_user` is hit after the RabbitMQ message is sent.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had `process.exit(0);` in my RabbitMQ code that I copied over from the docs.